# Rest login security

Tags: android, rest, security

It is safe to send login and password via http?
We are using Amazon AWS as server, so we can edit it.
What is the best option to secure the connection https is enough?
Or should we use OAuth or something like that?

Comment: Relative to your system(app), if you more security use of hight level security like OAuth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No it isn't. You have to use HTTPS to secure it. Everything that is sent by HTTP is vulnerable to MITM attack (including request params, HTML, JS, ...)
- OAuth wasn't designed to increase security of the server. It has different purpose. You can take a look on this article about the authentication methodologies on the web: 
  https://github.com/teesloane/Auth-Boss
- Don't forget to secure your backend server properly.